# String turns to question marks in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, internet-explorer, hebrew

I'm transferring String variable from js to controller using ajax. the String is in hebrew. In chrome it works fine and the controller gets the real String, but in IE (9) the String turns to question marks when it arrives to the controller. What am i missing here?

```
$.ajax({
        url:"/goblin/changeComment",
        type:'GET',
        data: dataValues,
        dataType: 'json', 
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        success: function() {
            ////not important code
        }
});
```

Of course i got this meta tag im my JSP

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: This kind of problems is typically a big pain in the a!$. THe problem could be located at server-side but as you don't have any trouble with other browsers, it is most probably client-side, ie : IE configuration set to wrong charset... But to answer your last question, yes, in addition, IE(9) sucks, not specifically because of that.

Comment: No, IE isn't sucks... but it does, though

Comment: Uneducated guess: Open up developer tools and make sure it's not in old-browser emulation mode for any given reason? (And make sure it has <!DOCTYPE HTML>)

Comment: wrong guess:( unfortunately...